# My next and previous button working only once but i want to make it continue but how?

Tags: android, arrays, switch-statement, buttonclick

i have 2 images on one page and i want to change it 3 times by using next and previous button like (1-2 images) then (3-4 images) and then (5-6 images) and then i click on previous button then it show like (3-4 images) then (1-2 images). My code is working only once when i complete it's loop then click on next or previous button then nothing happen, if you find any mistake in my code then correct me, here's my java code:

```
 public class AlifPics extends Activity  {  

    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;
    TextView text5;  
    TextView text6;   
    TextView text7;
    ImageView img1;
    ImageButton imgBut1;
    ImageButton imgBut2; 
    ImageButton nextBtn;        
    ImageButton preBtn;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.alif_pics);
  text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
  text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
  text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5); 
  text6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);  
  text7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
 img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 imgBut1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
 imgBut2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
 nextBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
 preBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);         
                  }   
      // this Menu Button method goes to MainActivity
           public void indexHuroof(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
          }

 int counter = 1;
  String[] textvalue1 = { "a2", "a3" };
  String[] textvalue2 = { "b2", "b3" };
  String[] textvalue3 = { "c2", "c3" };
  String[] textvalue4 = { "d2", "d3" }; 
  String[] textvalue5 = { "e2", "e3" };
  String[] textvalue6 = { "f2", "f3" };
  String[] textvalue7 = { "g2", "g3" };
      int[] myImageViewList1 = new int[] { R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3 }; // 123

   int[] myImageButtonList1 = new int[] { R.drawable.ibut2, R.drawable.ibut3 }; //     1,2,3

  int[] myImageButtonList2 = new int[] { R.drawable.ibut5, R.drawable.ibut6 }; // 4,5,6

  // my next ImageButton
    public void nextClick(View v) {
       try {

switch (counter) {
case 1: // first click
    text1.setText(textvalue1[0]);
    text2.setText(textvalue2[0]);
    text3.setText(textvalue3[0]);
    text4.setText(textvalue4[0]);
    text5.setText(textvalue5[0]);
    text6.setText(textvalue6[0]);
    text7.setText(textvalue7[0]);
    img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[0]);
    imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[0]);
    imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[0]);

    break;
case 2: // second click
    text1.setText(textvalue1[1]);
    text2.setText(textvalue2[1]);
    text3.setText(textvalue3[1]);
    text4.setText(textvalue4[1]);
    text5.setText(textvalue5[1]);
    text6.setText(textvalue6[1]);
    text7.setText(textvalue7[1]);
    img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[1]);
    imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[1]);
    imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[1]);
    break;
case 3: // third click
    text1.setText(textvalue1[2]);
    text2.setText(textvalue2[2]);
    text3.setText(textvalue3[2]);
    text4.setText(textvalue4[2]);
    text5.setText(textvalue5[2]);
    text6.setText(textvalue6[2]);
    text7.setText(textvalue7[2]);
    img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[2]);
    imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[2]);
    imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[2]);
    break;

default:
    break;
}

 } catch (Exception e) {
}
     counter++;
 }

// my previous ImageButton
       public void previousClick(View v) {
try
  {
       switch (counter) {
case 4: 
    text1.setText(textvalue1[1]);
    text2.setText(textvalue2[1]);
    text3.setText(textvalue3[1]);
    text4.setText(textvalue4[1]);
    text5.setText(textvalue5[1]);
    text6.setText(textvalue6[1]);
    text7.setText(textvalue7[1]);
    img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[1]);
    imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[1]);
    imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[1]);

    break;
case 3: 
    text1.setText(textvalue1[0]);
    text2.setText(textvalue2[0]);
    text3.setText(textvalue3[0]);
    text4.setText(textvalue4[0]);
    text5.setText(textvalue5[0]);
    text6.setText(textvalue6[0]);
    text7.setText(textvalue7[0]);
    img1.setImageResource(myImageViewList1[0]);
    imgBut1.setImageResource(myImageButtonList1[0]);
    imgBut2.setImageResource(myImageButtonList2[0]);
    break;
case 2: 
    text1.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
    text2.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
    text3.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
    text4.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
    text5.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
    text6.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
    text7.setText(R.string.textview1_default);
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    imgBut1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ibut1);
    imgBut2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ibut2);

    break;

default:
    break;
}

}    
      catch (Exception e) {
   }
counter++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: are you sure you want `counter++;` on `previousClick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the same question again.Anyways, it should be

```
counter--;
```

instead of

```
counter++;
```

in the last line of previousClick(View v)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, catching Exception and doing nothing is a really bad practice. At least have some sort of logging.

The actual problem seems to be caused from indefinitely incrementing count variable. You should reset it or use modulo.